# Looping through a SimpleXML with foreach in php

Tags: php, simplexml, stdclass

I'm trying to get the array values into the next SimpleXMLElement Object to get the [property] values, but I am not sure what is the best way to loop this object with an foreach in PHP,

Object code that I am getting:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [nowplaying-info] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [mountName] => KDLDFMAAC
                            [timestamp] => 1621880102
                            [type] => track
                        )

                    [property] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 248000
                            [1] => 1621880102606
                            [2] =>    LOS ANGELES AZULES FT PEPE AGILAR
                            [3] => 97008
                            [4] => NI CONTIGO NI SIN TI
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [mountName] => KDLDFMAAC
                            [timestamp] => 1621879804
                            [type] => track
                        )

                    [property] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 185000
                            [1] => 1621879804060
                            [2] => 
 
FITO OLIVARES
                            [3] => 97754
                            [4] => JUANA LA CUBANA
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [mountName] => KDLDFMAAC
                            [timestamp] => 1621879192
                            [type] => track
                        )

                    [property] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 252000
                            [1] => 1621879192436
                            [2] =>    CHON ARAUZA
                            [3] => 97076
                            [4] => UN MONTON DE ESTRELLAS
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Could you please help with the  best way to looping inside this object?

Thanks!

Comment: So you just want the `property` values and nothing else?  And do what with them?

Comment: See the examples in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php If that doesn't help, ask something more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://np.tritondigital.com/public/nowplaying?mountName=KFRQFMAAC&numberToFetch=3&eventType=track&request.preventCache=1621376522745');
$tracks = [];
foreach($xml->{'nowplaying-info'} as $item)
{
     $properties = [];
     foreach ($item->property as $prop)  $properties[] = (String) $prop;
     $tracks[]=$properties;
}

print_r($tracks);
```

preview it here: https://www.tehplayground.com/8zX2DrFsjVjT1IUK

---

```
// output: 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03:07
            [1] => 1622057699278
            [2] => LIVE AND LET DIE
            [3] => 18281
            [4] => PAUL MCCARTNEY & WINGS
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 04:20
            [1] => 1622057449584
            [2] => DREAMS
            [3] => 18269
            [4] => FLEETWOOD MAC
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 05:03
            [1] => 1622057144393
            .....
```

Comment: If that's all they want, `$result = array_column($xml->{'nowplaying-info'}, 'property');` then merge if needed.

Comment: @AndresGomez - I updated my answer based on the remote URL for the XML file. Take a look and see if this helps

Answer (score -1):

here is an example :

advantage is in one line, I don't think you'll find better :)

return 100% array not object of XMLElement

example for xml which does not contain DATA,

for xml with CDATA see:
[example XML with CDATA to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67677123/looping-through-a-simplexml-with-foreach-in-php/67709138#67709138)

```
array_map(function ($param) {
                    return next($param);
                }, current((new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('newXMLDocument.xml')))->children()))
```

assuming the XML file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<nowplaying-info-list>
    <nowplaying-info mountName="KDLDFMAAC" timestamp="1621880102" type="track">
        <property>248000</property>
        <property>1621880102606</property>
        <property>LOS ANGELES AZULES FT PEPE AGILAR</property>
        <property>97008</property>
        <property>NI CONTIGO NI SIN TI</property>
    </nowplaying-info>
    <nowplaying-info mountName="KDLDFMAAC" timestamp="1621879804" type="track">
        <property>185000</property>
        <property>1621879804060</property>
        <property>FITO OLIVARES</property>
        <property>97754</property>
        <property>JUANA LA CUBANA</property>
    </nowplaying-info>
    <nowplaying-info mountName="KDLDFMAAC" timestamp="1621879192" type="track">
        <property>252000</property>
        <property>1621879192436</property>
        <property>CHON ARAUZA</property>
        <property>97076</property>
        <property>UN MONTON DE ESTRELLAS</property>
    </nowplaying-info>
</nowplaying-info-list>
```

if you want to dump

```
echo nl2br(print_r(array_map(function ($param) {
                    return next($param);
                }, current((new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('newXMLDocument.xml')))->children())), true));
```

otherwise please give the example xml file !

Comment: This is an example XML that I need to parse: https://np.tritondigital.com/public/nowplaying?mountName=KFRQFMAAC&numberToFetch=3&eventType=track&request.preventCache=1621376522745

Comment: @andrés-gómez ok, look at my new answer i hope it meets your needs !?

Comment: Sorry, this does not return 100% array. It returns an array of simpleXML objects. You can see it here: https://www.tehplayground.com/Fsu1xSK13ueOXbax

Comment: @kinglish example for xml which does not contain DATA, 
for xml with CDATA see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67677123/looping-through-a-simplexml-with-foreach-in-php/67709138#67709138

Answer (score -1):

An example XML conversion with CDATA to array

without indexing :

```
    array_map(function ($nowplaying) {
        return array_map(function ($property) {
    return (string) $property;
}, next($nowplaying));
    }, current((new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('nowplaying.xml')))->children()))
```

result

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    0 => "05:05"
    1 => "1622016640460"
    2 => "YOU'VE GOT ANOTHER THING COMIN'"
    3 => "23008"
    4 => "JUDAS PRIEST"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    0 => "04:22"
    1 => "1622016380462"
    2 => "DREAM ON"
    3 => "20354"
    4 => "AEROSMITH"
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    0 => "03:54"
    1 => "1622016139890"
    2 => "ALL ALONG THE WATCHTOWER"
    3 => "20112"
    4 => "HENDRIX, JIMI"
  ]
]
```

with indexation :

```
array_map(function ($nowplaying) {
    return array_combine(array_map(function ($property) {
        return current($property)['name'];
    }, next($nowplaying)), array_map(function ($property) {
        return (string) $property;
    }, next($nowplaying)));
}, current((new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('nowplaying.xml')))->children()))
```

result

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "cue_time_duration" => "05:05"
    "cue_time_start" => "1622016640460"
    "cue_title" => "YOU'VE GOT ANOTHER THING COMIN'"
    "program_id" => "23008"
    "track_artist_name" => "JUDAS PRIEST"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "cue_time_duration" => "04:22"
    "cue_time_start" => "1622016380462"
    "cue_title" => "DREAM ON"
    "program_id" => "20354"
    "track_artist_name" => "AEROSMITH"
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    "cue_time_duration" => "03:54"
    "cue_time_start" => "1622016139890"
    "cue_title" => "ALL ALONG THE WATCHTOWER"
    "program_id" => "20112"
    "track_artist_name" => "HENDRIX, JIMI"
  ]
]
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nowplaying-info-list>
    <nowplaying-info mountName="KFRQFMAAC" timestamp="1622016640" type="track">
        <property name="cue_time_duration"><![CDATA[05:05]]></property>
        <property name="cue_time_start"><![CDATA[1622016640460]]></property>
        <property name="cue_title"><![CDATA[YOU'VE GOT ANOTHER THING COMIN']]></property>
        <property name="program_id"><![CDATA[23008]]></property>
        <property name="track_artist_name"><![CDATA[JUDAS PRIEST]]></property>
    </nowplaying-info>
    <nowplaying-info mountName="KFRQFMAAC" timestamp="1622016380" type="track">
        <property name="cue_time_duration"><![CDATA[04:22]]></property>
        <property name="cue_time_start"><![CDATA[1622016380462]]></property>
        <property name="cue_title"><![CDATA[DREAM ON]]></property>
        <property name="program_id"><![CDATA[20354]]></property>
        <property name="track_artist_name"><![CDATA[AEROSMITH]]></property>
    </nowplaying-info>
    <nowplaying-info mountName="KFRQFMAAC" timestamp="1622016139" type="track">
        <property name="cue_time_duration"><![CDATA[03:54]]></property>
        <property name="cue_time_start"><![CDATA[1622016139890]]></property>
        <property name="cue_title"><![CDATA[ALL ALONG THE WATCHTOWER]]></property>
        <property name="program_id"><![CDATA[20112]]></property>
        <property name="track_artist_name"><![CDATA[HENDRIX, JIMI]]></property>
    </nowplaying-info>
</nowplaying-info-list>
```